# Open files limit not reflecting config changes

Tags: security, ulimit

I'm trying to increase the max open files hard (and soft) limit indicated by `ulimit -Hn`. But no matter what configuration I change, it stays on `4096` even after rebooting.

In my `/etc/security/limits.conf`, I have the following entries (everything else is commented out):

```
* soft nofile 10000
* hard nofile 50000
```

My `/etc/pam.d/common-session` looks as follows:

```
session [default=1] pam_permit.so
session requisit    pam_deny.so
session required    pam_permit.so
session optional    pam_umask.so
session required    pam_unix.so 
session required    pam_limits.so
session optional    pam_systemd.so 
session optional    pam_cgfs.so -c freezer,memory,name=systemd
```

Why isn't the hard limit changed to `50000`, i.e. are there any other mechanisms affecting it?

**Update:**

Weirdly enough, it behaves differently when `su`ing to myself first, i.e.

```
$ whoami && ulimit -Hn
jdoe
4096
$ su - jdoe
$ whoami && ulimit -Hn
jdoe
50000
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a long time, I found out you need to add

```
DefaultLimitNOFILE=65535
```

to `/etc/systemd/system.conf` and `/etc/systemd/user.conf` as well.

Comment: That's the answer only worked

Comment: Spent 3 hours figuring that out on my own. Thanks man, that really helped!!

Answer (score 0):

You should also use prlimit and update the value of the current session (Bash) you are in. Try running the below script.

```sh
echo "add openfiles limit..........................."
sudo cp /etc/security/limits.conf  /etc/security/orig_limits.conf
sudo cat <<EOT >> /etc/security/limits.conf
*               hard    nofile          33000 
*               soft    nofile          33000
root            hard    nofile          33000 
root            soft    nofile          33000
EOT

sudo echo "session required pam_limits.so" > /etc/pam.d/common-session
sudo ulimit -n 33000
ulimit -u unlimited

update_ulimit_per_pid(){
    sudo echo "prlimit for pid "$pid" before updating is "$(ulimit -n)
    sudo echo "Updating ulimit for pid: "$pid
    sudo prlimit --pid $pid --nofile=33000:33000
    sudo echo "prlimit for pid "$pid" after updating is "$(ulimit -n)
}

for pid in `ps -ef | grep 'bash' | awk '{print $2}'` ; do update_ulimit_per_pid ; done
```

This should work. This will not only update ulimit when you relogin, but also the in the bash session you are in.